# Bashscript with curl operation in parallel

Tags: bash, curl, gnu-parallel

I have a list with urls which I like to load with CURL and do some operations on the result with a bash script.
Since it are almost 100k requests I like to run this in parallel.
I already looked into GNU parallel, but how am I going to glue all together? Thanks!

The bashscript:

```
while read URL; do
curl -L -H "Accept: application/unixref+xml" $URL > temp.xml;

YEAR=$(xmllint --xpath '//year' temp.xml);
MONTH=$(xmllint --xpath '(//date/month)[1]' temp.xml);

echo "$URL;$YEAR;$MONTH" >> results.csv;

sed -i '1d' urls.txt;

done < urls.txt;
```

Comment: I wouldn't modify `urls.txt` inside the loop while reading from it. At best, it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be modifying the input list of URLs as you make each HTTP request.  And having multiple appenders writing to the same output file from different processes will likely end in tears.

Put most of your commands in a separate script (named, say, `geturl.sh`) that could be invoked with the URL as a parameter, and writes its line of output to standard out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
URL="${1}"
curl -L -H "Accept: application/unixref+xml" "${URL}" > /tmp/$$.xml
YEAR="$(xmllint --xpath '//year' /tmp/.xml)"
MONTH="$(xmllint --xpath '(//date/month)[1]' /tmp/$$.xml)"
rm -f /tmp/$$.xml
echo "${URL};${YEAR};${MONTH}"
```

Then invoke as follows (here we let `parallel` merge the outputs from the various threads line by line):

```
parallel --line-buffer geturl.sh < urls.txt > results.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I did a testrun for 100 urls, but it look like it doesnt perform any better timewise than a serial version. Could curl be the problem? I'm runnig CygWin

Comment: Try running some more jobs in parallel: `parallel -j100` Also be aware that --line-buffer is much slower than the default (buffer a full job at a time).

Comment: Thanks adding -j100 improves the performances. Is there an alternative for --line-buffer?

Comment: Not sure you even need `--line-buffer` - I threw that in out of an abundance of caution.

Comment: I ran parallel without --line-buffer and it still works although it doesn't speed up the process. I ran some tests and it Doesn't matter if I select -j100 or -j5 it always takes 6 min to run the entire batch, can't this be improved? Or is downloading the urls just the bottleneck? Unfortunately I can't run multithreaded Curl in CygWIn..

Comment: Ouch, cygwin.  Spawning processes is more expensive on cygwin than on actual unix.  Might invoking an XML parsing utility twice per file be part of the overhead?  Also, you might try restructuring your scripts to get `curl` to fetch lots of URLs in one execution (use `split` to break up your list of URLs).  But the best approach would probably to write a perl/python/ruby script that downloads and parses the XMLs within the script, and split up your work among several simultaneous runs of that.